# Which Android Classes can be used to enable an action for every event in a specific calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar, drag-and-drop

I'm looking to see if this problem is feasible. I want to create an Android app that allows a user to enable Do Not Disturb for every event in user-specified calendars. I've already looked into the AlarmManager class, and it does not seem to work for this purpose. A single AlarmManager instance would work for one half of one event (turning Do Not Disturb On). Another AlarmManager instance would be required to turn Do Not Disturb off. This would have to repeat for every event (which is variable) in the specified calendars. Is there an easier approach to this, or am I looking at this problem all wrong? I know that this has been done in stock Android, but it only works for one calendar at a time. If there is a better solution to this, could you point me toward the proper Android SDK classes? I do not need a code example. Thanks.